# How do wire in my own Custom Object into an email

Tags: email

I am sending an email. I want to wire in my own custom object into the email.

According to the doc for SingleEmailMessage the whatIds can only be:
Account, Asset, Campaign, Case, Contract, Opportunity, Order, Product, Solution, Custom

and for MassEmailMessage the whatIds can only be:
Contract, Case, Opportunity, Product

So how do I wire in my own custom object?

To make matters more interesting if the target object is of type User, the setWhatIds() can't be invoked at all?  How do I get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think for SingleEmailMessage you can also specify a custom object ID as the whatId, i've done that on numerous occasions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setTargetObjectId()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) if you're using an email template.

Something like that should get you started:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
msg.setTargetObjectId(contactId);
msg.setWhatId(accountId);
msg.setTemplateId(emailTemplateId);
msg.SaveAsActivity = true;
// ...
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.singleEmailMessage[] { msg });
```