# SaveAsActivity is not allowed with whatId that is not supported as a task whatId

Tags: apex, email, emailmessage, saveasactivity, activity

While trying to create a custom business rule using Apex I got the error:

`INVALID_ID_FIELD, SaveAsActivity is not allowed with whatId that is not supported as a task whatId.`

...and found out that it was caused by the method `setSaveAsActivity` on my code, that was like:

```
msg.setSaveAsActivity(true); // "msg" is a SingleEmailMessage
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message can be a little confusing, but this error can be thrown if your main object (`relatedTo` in your template) doesn't have the "Allow Activities" option checked.

Checking this option will solve this issue.

This error message should be modified to something like "SaveSetAsActivity is not supported on objects that do not allow activities."

Comment: Probably? Or definitely? It makes sense that you wouldn't be able to save activities to an object which wouldn't allow them anyway.

Comment: I used "probably" because I really don't know if there are other circumstances that can result in the same error.

Comment: You might just clarify whether or not it solved your error.

Comment: Ok, done. Removed "probably".